# PHP URL Redirect (Getting full URL + GET)

Tags: php

How would I get just the last part to my URL?

Ex.

```
?page=home&optional=lol
```

I am not familiar with any of the server commands, so much help would be appreciated. Also note that the GET variables are dynamic and will be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The QUERY_STRING server variable should be what you're looking for:

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [parse_url](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Getting the full URL of the page is a bit complicated, but not very:

```
$pageURL = 'http';
if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
$pageURL .= "://";
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
   $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
}
else {
   $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
}
$parsed_url = parse_url($pageURL);
$qs = $parsed_url['query']; //query string, this is the ? part of the URL
```

Comment: Why parse the whole thing? `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` already provides the query string.

Answer (score 0):

This can be found in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`